# Java FileInputStream

Tags: java, arrays, java-io, fileinputstream

I am trying to use a FileInputStream to essentially read in a text file, and then output it in a different text file. However, I always get very strange characters when I do this. I'm sure it's some simple mistake I'm making, thanks for any help or pointing me in the right direction. Here's what I've got so far.

```
    File sendFile = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sendFile);
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    while(fileIn.read(buf) > 0) {
        System.out.println(buf);
    }
```

The file it is reading from is just a big text file of regular ASCII characters. Whenever I do the system.out.println, however, I get the output [B@a422ede. Any ideas on how to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Note that you can't read text/strings/characters with an `InputStream`. You need a `Reader` for that. You can convert bytes to characters with an `InputStreamReader`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are printing a byte array object itself, rather than printing its content. You should construct a String from the buffer and a length, and print that String instead. The constructor to use for this is

```
String s = new String(buf, 0, len, charsetName);
```

Above, len should be the value returned by the call of the read() method. The charsetName should represent the encoding used by the underlying file.

Comment: No, that's definitely not the constructor to use! Whenever you're converting from bytes to a string or from a string to bytes, you *need an encoding*! `new String(bytes, encoding)`. If you don't specify an encoding, you get the platform default, which is for all intents and purposes random. Also you can't use any random offset and length into a buffer, you may end up cutting off a multibyte character.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström You're right, I added the 4-th arg. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `len` should not be the value returned by the `read()` method, as it may cut in the middle of a multibyte character and isn't guaranteed to read all of the file. Use an `InputStreamReader` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from a file to another file, you shouldn't convert the bytes to a string at all, just write the bytes read into the other file.

If your intention is to convert a text file from an encoding to another, read from a `new InputStreamReader(in, sourceEncoding)`, and write to a `new OutputStreamWriter(out, targetEncoding)`.

Comment: All, pay attention to christoffer-hammarstrom@'s comments on other answer's here as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because printing `buf` will print the reference to the byte array, not the bytes themselves as String as you would expect. You need to do `new String(buf)` to construct the byte array into string

Also consider using BufferedReader rather than creating your own buffer. With it you can just do

```
String line = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename.txt")).readLine();
```

Comment: No, never use `FileReader`, it should be deprecated, because it has no way of specifying an encoding. Which means your text will be randomly corrupted depending on the platform encoding, which is essentially random.

Comment: Also, never use `BufferedReader.readLine()` for data that you need to read exactly as it is. It eats your newline characters, so you can never be sure you have a perfect copy of the newlines in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should look like this:

```
int len;
while((len = fileIn.read(buf)) > 0) {
        System.out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
```

You are (a) using the wrong method and (b) ignoring the length returned by `read()`, other than checking it for `< 0.` So you are printing junk at the end of each buffer.

Answer (score -1):

the object 's defualt toString method is return object's id in the memory.
byte buf[] is an object.

you can print using this.

```
File sendFile = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sendFile);
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];

while(fileIn.read(buf) > 0) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buf));
}
```

or

```
 File sendFile = new File(fileName);
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sendFile);
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
int len=0;
while((len=fileIn.read(buf)) > 0) {
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        System.out.print(buf[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The first version does not work as it takes no account of the length returned by `read()`. The second version is several times as complex as necessary. All you need is `System.out.write(buf, 0, len);`